# Bold text using imagefttext() in PHP

Tags: php

I have the below code and I want to bold the output.

Example:

This code;

```
$info['users_online']);
```

Outputs the users online count from my database. I want the number that is being output on the image to be bold.

Full code:

```
<?php
/db info all here/
    $getInfo = mysql_query("SELECT users_online FROM server_status");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo);
{

$image = imagecreatefrompng("banner.png"); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 1, 1, 1); 
imagefttext($image, 6.5, 1, 293, 68, $black, 'volter.ttf', $info['users_online']);
header('Content-type: image/png'); 
imagepng($image); 
imagedestroy($image); 
}
?>
```

Don't mind the "/db info all here/" part. I just need the users_online to be bold when it is outputted on the image. Right now, it's not bold.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a bold font instead of `'volter.ttf'`.

Comment: you should change the title and tags and mention that you are dealing with text in a image.

Comment: Do you have volter-bold.ttf ?

Comment: Why embed this in an image anyway? Why not simply wrap the text in a styled div?

Comment: Like other users said... you should use a bold font.

Comment: @defaultNINJA That doesn't work; when adding text to an image in this fashion, only a literal string is supported, so the result would be HTML tags in the image, which is probably not useful in most circumstances.

Comment: I'm going to use the volter-bold.ttf and see if that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bold font. For example a bold version of volter.ttf.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to replace the font file you're currently using (`volter.ttf`) with one which contains the same font, but in bold weight. If you're unable to do so, you might be able to produce a "pseudo-bold" effect by writing the string several times with a slight X-coordinate offset each time, but frankly at that point it's a lot easier just to change the font to something you can find in bold.